# Manipulating windows application from a java program

Tags: java, windows-7

I have a project for speech recognition in my college. So far its going ok. But I need to implement other features too. How do I manipulate an external application? Like manipulating a browser, say open a new tab, or search for 'something' in google, or visit a site? I can open the applications like:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start chrome.exe");
```

Or

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad.exe");
```

But then how to manipulate them? Suppose I want my program to write the words in the notepad or ms word as I am speaking. How do I do that? Please kindly help me solve the problem. I will be very grateful. Thank you.

Comment: You will need a JNI/JNA solution, even if you tried doing this through the use of Robot, just been able to find and focus a window is a native OS issue which Java can't do out of the box by itself